# Redux: Adding items to array mutates initial state

Tags: arrays, reactjs, redux

I have a question about mutating state in redux but especially an array.

Whenever I am adding something to array I am always sending the new array which has this new item. The same for removing. So everytime I send ,,new array''.

my redux:

```
case SET_RECIPIENTS: {
      return {
        ...state,
        form: {
          ...state.form,
          sms: {
            ...state.form.sms,
            to: [...action.to]
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

And everything is fine... except one thing. When i want to clear the array (to be empty), I am setting the initial state which is

```
export const initialState = {

  form: {
    sms: {
      to: [],
      sender: "", 
      message: ""
    }
    }
    }
```

And my clearing:

```
 case CLEAR_FORM: {
      return {
        ...state,
        form: initialState.form,
      };
    }
```

Then I see then the original to array is mutated, and I dont see empty array there...
The weird thing is that for Strings it works as I expected to work. I am setting the same way ,,message'' field and clearing is wiping out the value.

Thanks for tips

Answer (score 0):

that is because you are assigning the with `initalState.form` directly so  instead of creating a new object the `form` key just points to `initialState.form` object and whenever you change the form it will change the `initalState.form`

so you need to create new objects while assigning like this:

```
case CLEAR_FORM: {
  return {
    ...state,
    form: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(initialState.form)),
  };
}
```

since `initialState.form` is a nested object so we can use JSON.stringify and JSON.parse to clone a nested object
we are not using any date, undefined so JSON methods should be fine.

Comment: Sorry, it didnt help

Answer (score 0):

The issue was, that when I was getting the current state of to from redux by selector, i was using .push method to add the new value to the array form redux which caused mutating the state.
I fixed it by spread operator.